# What is the Object parameter in UnityEngine.Debug.Log(string, Object) for?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've checked [UnityEngine.Debug.Log method documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) but I cannot find the use of the second parameter `Object`. I have tried one of my GameObjects and nothing particular happens, it is like passing anything. I still get an unuseful extra line`UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Object)` I wonder what would one use it for?

Since I haven't noticed any merit I find it annoying. The line `UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Object)` is just space wasted in the Console. I could have twice the number of rows in it.

[image: Console with wasted space]

What is that parameter for?

**EDIT** Thanks to Adam now I know!. `Object` might become handy sometimes however I still think it is a waste of space in the Console window.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the extra line "UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Object)" but still see your messages in console, you can just add a "\n" to then end of each message. See here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/804262/hide-unityenginedebuglogobject-in-console.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation just says it is the 'context' to which the debug message applies, which perhaps isn't especially useful, but does hint at its use. The connection that it makes between the object and the debug message can be used to locate the object you're debugging, try double clicking on a message in the debug log to see this.

Comment: I see now!. I didn't see this before because I was trying with an MonoBehaviour script object. This time I tried with a GameObject and double clicking it highlight the same object in the hierarchy window. Thanks!